# Count the number of colors used to color a graph in python

Tags: python, graph, colors, count, theory

I need help with my code to count the number of colors that used to color the graph
I wrote a small code to print a list of colors and now I need to count them

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5])
g.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(4,5)])
C = set(xrange(12))
color = {}

for u in g:
    interdits = set([color[v] for v in g.neighbors(u) if color.has_key(v)])
    color[u] = min(C-interdits)

print color
```

the output :

> > > ```
> > > {1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2}
> > > ```

instead of this output I want to count the colors so the result should be 3
Any idea or help??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely read through a [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).  You might also want to use ipython or IDLE or something where you can easily see what methods are living inside an object without having to consult the docs, which is an easy way to experiment.  `dir(some_object_name)` works too but I don't find it as convenient as hitting tab in ipython, but YMMV.

In any case, once you have your `color` variable:

```
>>> color
{1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2}
>>> color.values()
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
>>> set(color.values())
set([0, 1, 2])
>>> len(set(color.values()))
3
```

(And just to make sure, this the number of colours you *used*, not the minimum number of colours needed.)

Answer (score 1):

The highest number color used can be found with

```
max(color.values())
```

but they're numbered from zero so you probably want

```
max(color.values()) + 1
```

While it likely doesn't really matter, this doesn't require building a list of all the colors used, or hashing each entry, unlike the `set` method.

Also, `has_key` is deprecated. Use `v in color` instead.

Comment: (I think I know the guy who originally wrote that has_key line, and it's a habit of his. :-)  I actually prefer len(set) here, because it doesn't depend upon the implementation details of how the colours were chosen.  (While it's not so relevant here, I can think of several Sage graph theory bugs which could be traced to someone's assumption that the nodes had labels [0..n-1].)

Comment: @DSM Interesting. It seemed like the logical assumption to me, but I certainly don't know it to be true.